# Eclipse maven projects error

Tags: eclipse, pom.xml, snapshot, eclipse-kepler

I import a maven project from web and once I open the project in eclipse Kepler I have the following error in POM:

```
Missing artifact org.modeshape:modeshape-common:jar:3.7-SNAPSHOT
```

any help please

Comment: Is that artifact directly referenced in your POM? Is it an indirect reference? Should it not be showing up at all? You have to provide some more details.

Comment: what do you expect my full pom file ????

Comment: That would be helpful, sure. Or just more details like I asked for. Why would Eclipse be expecting that artifact? Do you think Eclipse should be able to find it, or are you wondering where this is even coming from? I really don't know where to begin.